# How to set value of certain property on deserialization?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

I have a class with properties that setters depend on `VeryImportantProperty`. But the property shouldn't be serialized by design.

So, when I receive JSON, I have to set `VeryImportantProperty` during deserialization and before setting other properties.

I suppose it could be done by modifying `ContractResolver`. I store value for `VeryImportantProperty` there, but I don't know how to assign it

I tried to use following `ContractResolver`, but it does not affect

```cs
public class MyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public VeryImportantClass VeryImportantPropertyValue { get; set; }
        
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
            
        if (property.PropertyName == "VeryImportantProperty" && VeryImportantPropertyValue != null)
        {
            property.DefaultValue = VeryImportantPropertyValue;
            property.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate;
            property.Order = -1;
        }

        return property;
    }
}
```

Comment: What will be the value for your VeryImportantProperty? Will it be calculated from other properties of same class? ... or is it value you have to provide when calling Deserialize()? A code example would help to understand the problem better.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I will provide value when calling Deserialize() (set it to ContractResolver property for example)

Comment: Please try to share with us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Btw. it sounds like you simply have two different models. A dto to represent the json request and something else you need in your app. It may be an option to simply use two different classes for this.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I would, but unforteneately there is thousands of such legacy classes. So I have to look for another solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating `ContractResolver` that overrides `CreateContract` to set `Converter` to custom one that overrides `Create` to pass my `VeryImportantProperty` to constructor

Code:

```cs
public class MyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public VeryImportantClass VeryImportantPropertyValue { get; set; }

    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);
        if (VeryImportantPropertyValue == null)
            return contract;

        // Solution for multiple classes is commented
        if (objectType == typeof(ContainerClass)/* || objectType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseContainer))*/)
        {
            contract.Converter = new ImportantClassConverter(VeryImportantPropertyValue);
        }
        return contract;
    }

    private class ImportantClassConverter: CustomCreationConverter<VeryImportantClass>
    {
        public EntityConverter(VeryImportantClass veryImportantPropertyValue)
        {
            _veryImportantPropertyValue= veryImportantPropertyValue;
        }

        private readonly VeryImportantClass _veryImportantPropertyValue;

        public override VeryImportantClass Create(Type objectType)
        {
            // Might be simplified but it was used for multiple container classes with one parent
            return objectType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(ContainerClass) })
                ?.Invoke(new[] { _veryImportantPropertyValue }) as ContainerClass;
        }
    }
}
```